# $\int^b_af(x)\,x^k \, dx=\int^b_ag(x)\,x^k \, dx$ , for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

> If $f, g\in \mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ and $$\int^b_af(x)\,x^k \, dx=\int^b_ag(x)\,x^k \, dx, \text{ for all } k \in \mathbb{N}$$ Prove that $f=g$.

I'm trying to prove this but I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem?

Comment: For you, $0\in\mathbb N$?

Answer (score 5):

Let $h:= f-g$. The hypothesis states that $ \int h p = 0$ for any polynomial $p$.

To begin, we apply Stone-Weierstrass to get that the polynomials are uniformly dense in $\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$.

In particular, for $\epsilon >0$, we can find a polynomial $p$ such that $ \| h-p \|_\infty < \varepsilon $.

Thus, $$ \left| \int h^2 \right| \leq \left| \int h p \right| + \left| \int h (h-p) \right| \leq \varepsilon \left| \int h \right|. $$

Since $h$ is continuous, $| \int h | < \infty $ and hence $ \int h^2  = 0$.

But for any continuous function, this is precisely $h=0$ or $f=g$.

Comment: Not accurate as written. The hypothesis states that $\ldots$ for any polynomial $p(x)$ *that does not have a constant term*. And these polynomials are not dense by Stone-Weierstrass as it does not contain a non-zero constant function. The trick is to do it as in the other answer. Also Stone-Weierstrass is overkill here as Weierstass approximation theorem will do.

Comment: Ah, i see. I didn't realise he wasn't including constant polynomials - I assumed he had included $ 0 \in \mathbb{N}$. But yes, it easy to tweak this by considering $xh$ instead. However, I think the point about the Weierstrass approximation theorem is kind of redundant, as SW is a stronger version with an almost identical proof. To me, the Weierstrass approximation theorem is only useful as a motivating example for SW.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_a ^{b} xf(x) x^{k} dx=\int_a ^{b} xf(x) x^{k} dx$ for $k \geq 0$. Hence, by standard Weierstarss approximation $xf(x)=xg(x)$ for all x which gives what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an overkill. One knows by tweaking [Stone-Weierstrass](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) that polynomials are dense in $C[a, b] $ with $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ norm. Let $\mathcal P$ be the set of all polynomials.  What you have written is equivalent to $$<f-g, p>=\int_a^b (f(x) - g(x) ) p(x) = 0$$ for every polynomial $p\in \mathcal P$. Hence $f(x)-g(x) $ is in the annihilator of $\mathcal P$, namely $\mathcal {P} ^\perp$ and since $\mathcal P$ is dense we get $f(x) - g(x) \in \mathcal {P} ^\perp=\{0\} $. Hence $f=g$.

**Edit/Remark.** the same idea also works if $0\notin\mathbb{N}$. That proof is left to the reader.

Comment: Shashi, the equation $<f-g,p>=0$ is available only when there is no constant term. The whole point of this question seems to be that k=0 is not included in the hypothesis. My solution shows how to get over this difficulty.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see that yours can be done if $0\notin \mathbb N$ but the OP still did not specify whether $0\in\mathbb{N}$ or not. I added some remarks to make the post complete. Thanks!